# CFWheels - How do I increment a number in a database column?

Tags: orm, coldfusion, railo, cfwheels

Just wondering, with CFWheels ORM, how I go about incrementing a number in a column?

In straight up SQL I would do something like:

```
UPDATE table 
SET field = field + 1 
WHERE ...
```

I'd like to avoid "fetching" the value from the column and incrementing it manually. I'll be doing a lot of this in my app, so it's an overhead I could do without (plus I'd also like to keep my code simple and elegant).

Could something like this work?

```
<cfset post = model("post").findByKey(99) />
<cfset post.update( myColumn = myColumn + 1 ) />
```

Appreciate some input.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can abstract this in the base `Model.cfc` if you need to repeat it a lot:

```
<cfcomponent extends="Wheels">
    <cffunction name="incrementColumn" returntype="boolean">
        <cfargument name="key" type="string" required="true">
        <cfargument name="property" type="string" required="true">

        <cfset local.record = this.findByKey(arguments.key)>
        <cfset local.record[arguments.property]++>

        <cfreturn local.record.update()>
    </cffunction>
</cfcomponent>
```

Then you can call it from your controller like so:

```
<cfif post = model("post").incrementColumn(params.key, "myColumn")>
    Success
<cfelse>
    Error
</cfif>
```

Comment: I haven't tried this yet, but logically it looks sound! Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

the orm in cfwheels doesn't support this. for stuff like that straight sql is the way to go. the best thing to do is to create a custom method on you model to encapsulate the logic.

Comment: This is such a shame! I would like to use 100% ORM. Oh well. Why would I store a custom SQL query on the model and not the controller.cfc that these controllers extend? So I could do super.updateNumber(); for example.

Comment: IMHO shame is when framework tries to do everything in the world.